# How to install gst-python (gstreamer python bind) on Mac OSX the easy way?

Tags: python, macos, macports, gstreamer

How can I install **gst-python**, which is GStreamer's python bind, on my Mac (Snow Leopard) the easy way? This will probably involve using a package-manager like [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) or [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/).

I've been looking for the package everywhere. Compiling is a real mess.

If this isn't possible, what are the alternatives? Detailed instruction are welcome. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the base MacPorts following the instructions [here](http://www.macports.org/install.php).  If you already have MacPorts installed, make sure the portfiles are up-to-date:

```
$ sudo port selfupdate
```

Then, depending on whether you want to use Python 2.6 or Python 2.7, install the appropriate port, either:

```
$ sudo port install py26-gst-python
```

or:

```
$ sudo port install py27-gst-python
```

and sit back and wait.  Be aware that those ports appear to pull in a *lot* of dependent packages including a MacPorts `Python` installation and `Gnome`, so it will likely take a while.  But, in the end, it should all just work.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea why *homebrew* doesn't have gst-python? I tried installing with it first and failed. It didn't find the package in its repository.

Comment: Perhaps because there are so many dependencies and perhaps because the MacPorts project has been around longer.  Keep in mind that both the MacPorts and Homebrew and Fink projects are volunteer efforts.  If no one involved with the project has the interest or time to adapt and test a port, it won't happen.  I'm sure both projects are always looking for help.

Comment: In case anyone's looking at this, `brew install gst-python` now works.

Comment: In case anyone's looking at this, `brew install gst-python` no longer works.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't post it as a comment because I only have 5 rep, but you actually can install it using: `brew install homebrew/versions/gst-python010`.

This obtains gst-python from the tap containing gst-python010.
The 010 at the end there shows the version 0.10.

Unfortunately, there is not a 1.0 version from Homebrew's taps or packages, currently.

There might be a updated version in the future.